# Linux: Is there a way to have multiple X displays with the Intel driver?

Tags: display, xorg

I have two monitors connected to an intel chipset (Sandybridge Desktop GT1) on VGA and DVI. With this `xorg.conf`, everything works great:

```
 Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Device0"
    Driver      "intel"
    Option "monitor-VGA1" "Monitor0"
    Option "monitor-HDMI1" "Monitor1"
 EndSection

 Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1600x900"
 EndSection

 Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    Option "RightOf" "Monitor0"
    Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
 EndSection
```

However, this is not what I want. This produces a single X display (:0.0) and windows are shared between the two screens. I would like two X displays to start two openbox sessions.

I have searched the web for a solution with no success. I tried a few configurations involving multiple "Device" sections, which did not work.

Is it possible to have multiple X displays with a chipset like the one I use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First note that --unless you are really, really sure this is what you want-- you probably want to do something completely different, like spanning with xinerama.

What you describe is a muti-seat setup, which has [some documentation here](http://www.x.org/wiki/Development/Documentation/Multiseat). It includes links for a number of distro specific howtos.

To accomplish two individual X-s without separate video cards, you'll have to use the Xephyr method, as Xorg (apparently) can't run several instances on one card (or for that matter one processor-built-in graphics adapter).

Comment: I'm not talking about two different X servers, but two displays (that is, two possible values for the $DISPLAY environment variable). With proprietary drivers for AMD or Nvidia cards, there's an option called something like "multi-desktop" which does just that. So `DISPLAY=:0.1 vlc` puts vlc in the corresponding screen. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.